# logical indexing in matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider the following example:

```
time = [733774,733774,733775,733775,733775,733776,733776];
depth = [0,10,0,5,10,0,10];
d = [1,1.3,1,2.5,2.5,1,1.2];
data = horzcat(time',depth',d');

dz = 1;
```

Here I have a number of measurements taken for three separate days. The first day has 2 measurements taken at 2 separate depths, the second day has 3 measurements taken at 3 depths and the third has 2 measurements taken at 2 depths.

I would like to generate a new variable 'newData' which linearly interpolated (interp1) the values in data. However, I would only like to do this if the number of measurements for any given day exceeds 2. So, for the example above this would only apply to 733775. Here I would like to take the depth measurements and increase the vertical resolution e.g.

```
newDepth = min(depth):dz:max(depth);
```

But only perform this for the days when the number of measurements exceed 2. The outcome of what I have described should therefore be:

```
733774  0
733774  10
733775  0
733775  1
733775  2
733775  3
733775  4
733775  5
733775  6
733775  7
733775  8
733775  9
733775  10
733776  0
733776  10
```

plus the interpolated values from 'data(:,3)'.

What would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: there's no depth 0 for 733775 in the output. Is that intentional? What if the depths are `[1 3 1]` for a given day? What if they are `[1 1 4]`? What if they are `[1 4 5]`? How should the interpolatio look in these cases?

Comment: It should be an interpolation from the minimum depth to the maximum at intervals of 1. Also, the depths would not be [1 3 1] in my example. Corrected the example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this (solving the edited version of the OP this time):

```
[idx,~,uniqueTimes] = grp2idx(time);

counts = hist(time,uniqueTimes);


%# expand data with counts greater than minCount
minCount = 2;
dz = 1;

expandedData = mat2cell(data,counts,3)

for ii = find(counts>minCount)'
    minZ = expandedData{ii}(1,2);
    maxZ = expandedData{ii}(end,2);

    intData(:,2) = (minZ:dz:maxZ)';
    intData(:,1) = expandedData{ii}(1,1);
    intData(:,3) = interp1(expandedData{ii}(:,2),expandedData{ii}(:,3),intData(:,2));

    expandedData{ii} = intData;

end

out = cat(1,expandedData{:})
```

Comment: thank you, I have now included an example of what I am trying to achieve. This is more specific to my actual problem.

Comment: to clarify, in the line expandedData = mat2cell(data,counts,3); does 3 refer to the number of unique days? or the column numbers?

Comment: @Kate: no, that refers to the number of columns in `data`, and could be replaced with `size(data,2)`.

Comment: I seem to be running into a problem when applying this to my own data. I receive the error 'Bad cell reference operation' following the line expandedData = mat2cell(data,counts,size(data,2)).

Comment: @Kate: I have a hard time reproducing that error. Are you sure that the data is the same format as in your question, and that you haven't accidentially defined e.g. `size` as an array?

Comment: I've altered that part of the code now and it works fine. I altered it to: for i = 1:length(expandedData);
    if size(expandedData{i},1) > minCount;
            %find min and max depths for each cell
        minZ = expandedData{i}(1,2);
        maxZ = expandedData{i}(end,2);
            %interpolate
        intData2= (minZ:dz:maxZ)';
        intData1 = expandedData{i}(1,1);
        intData3 = interp1(expandedData{i}(:,2),expandedData{i}(:,3),intData2);
            %combine arrays
        expandedData{i} = [repmat(intData1,size(intData2,1),1),intData2,intData3];
    end
end        thanks