# indexing to find corresponding number

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a time series of measurements taken at different depths of a water column. I have divided these into individual cells (for later) and require some help on how to complete the following: e.g.

```
    time = [733774,733774,733775,733775,733775,733776,733776];
    bthD = [20,10,0,15,10,20,10];
    bthA = (1000:100:1600);
    %Hypsographic
    Hypso = [(10:1:20)',(1000:100:2000)'];
    d = [1,1.3,1,2.5,2.5,1,1.2];
    data = horzcat(time',bthD',d');
    uniqueTimes = unique(time);
    counts = hist(time,uniqueTimes);
    newData = mat2cell(data,counts,length(uniqueTimes));
```

So, in newData I have three cells, that correspond to different days of measurements, in each cell I have newData(:,1) being time, newData(:,2) being depth, and newData(:,3) being the measurement. I would like to find what the area is at each depth in the cells, the area at different depths is given in the variable 'Hypso'.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You should collaborate with Kate; she works on the same data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471727/logical-indexing-in-matlab ;)

Comment: Agree, I found this a suitable example for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem formulation is excellent!  Very easy to understand what you need here.  All you need is the function [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).  Use the first column of `Hypso`, I assume, as your depth, and the second column as the area.  You can use the vectorized ability of the `interp1` function to find all values in one call:

```
areaAtDepth = interp1(Hypso(:,1),Hypso(:,2),bthD)

areaAtDepth =

  Columns 1 through 6

        2000        1000         NaN        1500        1000        2000

  Column 7

        1000
```

You'll notice the `Nan` in the third column of the output.  This is because it's associated depth, `0`, is outside the range of the data, or support of the data I believe.  You'll need to decide what you want to do when data is outside the range, or perhaps it never should be, so an error should be logged; it's up to you!  Let me know if you have any more questions!